# What is the difference between cgroups freeze and linux command "Kill - STOP pid" in golang?

Tags: linux, go, operating-system, cgroups

I use this [cgroups](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/containerd/cgroups#section-readme) package.

There are two interfaces I am interested in for `type Cgroup`. The one is `Freeze() error` and the other is `Thaw() error`.The description of them is as follows:

```golang
    ...
    // Freeze freezes or pauses all processes inside the cgroup
    Freeze() error
    // Thaw thaw or resumes all processes inside the cgroup
    Thaw() error
    ...
```

And there are two linux command that can pause and resume a process, which is `kill -STOP pid` and `kill -CONT pid`.

I wonder that if there is only one process in a cgroup, does it has any difference between these two ways to pause and resume the process? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both states were introduced in oct. 2016 in [`containerd/cgroups` commit b3f3344](https://github.com/containerd/cgroups/commit/b3f3344cdfcf61d99dfd75a329d12ac781aec48d) and refer to [cgroup v1 self-state](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/freezer-subsystem.txt#:%7E:text=Freezing%20a%20cgroup%20freezes%20all,THAWED%2C%20the%20cgroup%20is%20THAWED.&text=When%20written%2C%20sets%20the%20self%2Dstate%20of%20the%20cgroup.)

> The cgroup freezer is hierarchical.
>
> Freezing a cgroup freezes all tasks beloning to the cgroup and all its descendant cgroups.
> Each cgroup has its own state (self-state) and the state inherited from the parent (parent-state).
> Iff both states are THAWED, the cgroup is THAWED.

[CGroup Freezer](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/resource_management_guide/sec-freezer) states:

> `freezer.state` is only available in non-root cgroups and has three possible values:
>
> - `FROZEN` — tasks in the cgroup are suspended.
> - `FREEZING` — the system is in the process of suspending tasks in the cgroup.
> - `THAWED` — tasks in the cgroup have resumed.

Meaning ([here](https://titanwolf.org/Network/Articles/Article?AID=c5a472e2-7bde-4c29-964e-6d62c736ed67#gsc.tab=0)):

> The freezer subsystem is used to suspend and resume processes in the cgroup.
>
> Freezer has a control file: `freezer.state`, write `FROZEN` to this file, you can suspend the process in the cgroup, and write `THAWED` to this file, you can resume the suspended process.